# Icon showing in square shape in Seachbar react native paper

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have started react native just. I have an issue with *Searchbar* component using `react-native-paper` dependency.

I have installed

```
 "react-native-paper": "^4.7.2",
 "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0"
```

dependencies for that. I have used *Searchbar* component like,

```
<Searchbar
        style={styles.searchbarMargin}
        placeholder="Search"
        icon={()=><MaterialCommunityIcon name="magnify" size={20}/>}
      />
```

`import` statements are

```
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';
import MaterialCommunityIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';
```

I have already added

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

in *build_gradle* file still it is not showing *magnify* icon. Help me out.

**Note :** I have already cleaned cache for `npm` and `react-native` and uninstalled `node_modules` folder and installed packages again still it didn't work.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sorted out this by just run this command in terminal

```
npx react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

after successfully run the command you need to run

```
react-native run-android
```

command so you can able to see your desire icon.